# Filter rows in google sheets with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I was having problem filtering rows in google sheets based on cell value from a dropdown list. My online search hasn't provided anything that I could use (mostly because of my lack of programming knowledge which made me uncapable of possibly altering an online code to my needs).
Then I found the next pieces of code:

```
function filterRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sep");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i][38] === "NO") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  } 
}
```

```
function showAllRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sep");
  sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
}
```

I have assigned the two pieces of code to two different buttons and used an IF formula in column AL that returns "YES" or "NO".
As you can see, they achieve the filtering I want, but only for the sheet specified in the code.
I would like to apply the code to several different sheets and so the goal would be to get the code to "catch" the currently active sheet that the user is working on.
The truth is that I would prefer to use the cell value from the dropdown list to do the filtering (the users choose a value and the sheets automatically get filtered with that value - and use the second piece of code to show all the rows again) but as I mentioned I couldn;t find anything similar.
Can anyone please help?
I would be greatly appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function filterRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const v = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();//this cell is a dropdown
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == v) {
      sh.hideRows(i + 2)
    } else {
      sh.showRows(i + 2);
    }
  })
}
```

With this Sheet0:

Choosing YES

| YES | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| NO | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| NO | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| NO | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| NO | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| NO | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |

Choosing NO:

| NO | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| NO | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| NO | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| NO | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| NO | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

Additional Question:

```
function filterRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sr = 8; 
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const v = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();//this cell is a dropdown
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == v) {
      sh.hideRows(i + sr)
    } else {
      sh.showRows(i + sr);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper. Thank you very much for your answer. I tested it and really does the job! One last thing though: in my sheet, the range I want filtered begins from row 8 column A. The above rows need to remain visible all the time. How can your code be modified to achieve this?